# Calculate complex integral with pole at zero

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Calculate for $\alpha >0$ and $n \in {\mathbb Z}$.

$$
\oint_{\left\vert\,z\,\right\vert\ =\ \alpha} z^{n}\,{\rm d}z.
$$

Comment: Surely you mean $|z|=\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Also it is not a pole but a singularity.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large 2\,\pi\,{\rm i}\,\delta_{n + 1,0}}$.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done directly. Let $z=\alpha e^{i\theta}$ then substitute and integrate from $0$ to $2\pi$ for $n\neq -1$ you get zero and for $n=-1$ you get $2 \pi i$.

The integral becomes

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (\alpha e^{i\theta})^n i\alpha e^{i\theta} d\theta
=\alpha^{n+1} i\int_0^{2\pi}  e^{i(n+1)\theta} d\theta $$

Now if $n+1\neq 0$
then 
$$\int_0^{2\pi}  e^{i(n+1)\theta} d\theta =\frac{1}{i(n+1)}e^{i(n+1)\theta} |^{2\pi}_0=0$$

On the other hand if $n+1=0$ we have

$$ i\int_0^{2\pi}  d\theta =2\pi i$$

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate, because I don't see it?

Comment: There are three displayed equations.  Which of them is the first that you "don't see"?

Comment: @GEdgar the comment predates the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Write it as

$$\int_{|z-0|=\alpha} {1\over z^{-n}}\,dz=\int_{|z|=\alpha} {z\over z^{-n+1}}\,dz$$

Then by Cauchy's integral formula this is $2\pi i F^{(-n)}(0)$, where $F(z)=z$ and $F^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $F$, where a negative value for $n$ means take a primitive antiderivative, i.e. for $n<0$

$$F^{(n)}(z)={1\over (-n)!}z^{-n}.$$

But then, all of these functions are $0$ at $0$, unless $n=-1$, in which case we get $F^{(1)}(0)=F'(0)=1$, so the answer is $2\pi i$ in that case and $0$ otherwise.

---

I particularly advocate this approach because it's part of the point of complex analysis to learn how to use the major tools rather than ugly parametrizations which are almost universally horrific and *impossible* if the path is not **very** nice.

Comment: Doesn't Cauchy's integral formula need an n+1 in the denominator? So it would be the -n-1'th derivative?

Comment: @Lukas I picked the function $f(z)=z$, not $f(z)=1$, so that you're looking at ${z\over z^{-n+1}}$ which has the right form. Mostly so that it is easy to see the function $f$ naturally and so the derivative is just the $n^{th}$ and not some weird shift.

Comment: I see. Thank you. I think I understood. The point of the task probably was to show that Cauchy's formula works for negative n as well.

Comment: @Lukas indeed, though for $n\ge 0$ you don't even need the Cauchy formula, since you have Morera's theorem that says the integral is $0$ when the function is entire. I just chose to put the two cases together because it looks prettier to have one universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Line integrals $\int_\gamma f(z)\>dz$ are defined for  *chains* $\gamma$ (formal sums of *directed* arcs), and not for sets $S:=\{z\>|\>|z|=\alpha\}$. But never mind.

We all know that
$$z^n={1\over n+1}\>{d\over dz}\> z^{n+1}\qquad(n\ne-1)\ ,$$
and this implies
$$\int_\gamma z^n\>dz=0$$
for all $n\ne-1$ and all closed curves $\gamma$ not passing through $0$. Therefore it remains to compute
$$\int_\gamma{dz\over z}\ ,$$
where $$\gamma:\quad t\mapsto z(t):=\alpha\>e^{it}\qquad(0\leq t\leq2\pi)$$
is the circle of radius $\alpha>0$ around the origin. One obtains
$$\int_\gamma{dz\over z}=\int_0^{2\pi}{\dot z(t)\over z(t)}\>dt=\int_0^{2\pi} i\>dt=2\pi i\ .$$